# Can't Find Upgrade Patch for phpMyAdmin

Tags: build, phpmyadmin, upgrade, patch, whm

phpMyAdmin on my server is giving me a message

A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.1.7, released on 2014-02-09.

My tech support at MycPadmin.com cannot find the exact patch for the cpanel current version - WHM 11.40.1 (build 11).

Can you please tell me where to find this patch.  Thank you.

Comment: `My tech support at MycPadmin.com cannot find the exact patch`. Oh, really? Of course *we* know. The exact patch is `42`

Answer (score 0):

Since your hosting provider is using a packaged version distributed by cPanel, you can either download the official phpMyAdmin source and install it manually out side of the existing phpMyAdmin installation, or you can wait for cPanel to provide an update.

As an aside, phpMyAdmin provides a specific way for other packages that include phpMyAdmin (like cPanel in this case) to suppress that warning, and it's probably an oversight that they don't. In the meantime, you could also turn off the warning by editing your config.inc.php and adding the line `$cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;`